Is there a way to create a cross-region APIGateway v2 Http Integration?
Creating a cross-region APIGateway v2 Http Integration where the API gateway is in one region and the Lambda is in another using the AWS console is straightforward, as it is possible to select the "AWS Region" from which to look up existing Lambda functions.

Additionally, in CDK it is possible to create an HttpLambdaIntegration using the following example code taken straight from the AWS CDK documentation.

Given the above, it seems it should be possible to simply create an HttpLambdaIntegration using a Lambda function in another region by loading it via its ARN. However, when trying to use a Lambda in another region, which was loaded using the "fromFunctionArn" method in the Lambda construct library, CDK will throw the following error:
CREATE_FAILED | AWS::Lambda::Permission | myApi/GET--test/testIntegration-Permission
Resource handler returned message: "Functions from 'ap-southeast-3' are not reachable in this region ('ap-southeast-1')
(Service: Lambda, Status Code: 404, Request ID: -)" (RequestToken: -, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)

Is there perhaps a parameter or other configuration setting that might be required to enable cross-region Lambdas to be used in CDK or perhaps an alternative approach to the above methodology?
Thanks!

What is the error you get when you try to use a Lambda function in another region?

Good point - would have been helpful to have the actual error output.  Added in the error to the post.  Thanks!

If your Lambda stack is created in us-east-2 and you want your API Gateway stack to be created in us-east-1, you can achieve this by setting the crossRegionReferences: true option when instantiating your stack in the bin folder. This enables cross-region references between the stacks.
Here's an example:
const uatWebLayerLGIntegration = new WebLayerIntegration(PatternApp, `${client}WebLayerIntegrationStack-${stage}`, {
    userPool: CognitoStack.userPool,
    webLayerLambda: uatWebLayerFuction.webLayerLambda,
    clientPrefix: client,
    env: { account: deploymentAccount, region: 'us-east-1' }, // API Gateway region
    crossRegionReferences: true, // Enables cross-region references
    stage: stage, });

Key Points:
The env property specifies the AWS account and region for the stack deployment. Here, the API Gateway is explicitly set to be deployed in us-east-1.
The crossRegionReferences: true option ensures that resources in us-east-1 (API Gateway) can reference resources in us-east-2 (Lambda stack).
